# Zigzag level order traversal

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

> I am trying to do the zigzag level order traversal of a binary tree's nodes values (ie, from left to right, then right to left for the next level and alternate between) on https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/zigzag-level-order-traversal-bt/ But the compiler gives time limit exceeded error. How can I resolve it?

```
# Definition for a  binary tree node
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    # @param A : root node of tree
    # @return a list of list of integers
    def zigzagLevelOrder(self, A):
        st_crt_lvl =[A]
        st_nxt_lvl =[]
        ans_list = []

        while st_crt_lvl:
            u = st_crt_lvl.pop(0)
            ans_list.append(u.val) 
            if u.left:
                st_nxt_lvl.append(u.left)
            if u.right:
                st_nxt_lvl.append(u.right)
            while st_nxt_lvl:
                u = st_nxt_lvl.pop()
                ans_list.append(u.val)

                if u.right:
                    st_crt_lvl.append(u.right)
                if u.left:
                    st_crt_lvl.append(u.left)


        return ans_list
```

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate multiple inner `while` loops from your code, by making the  queue `st_nxt_lvl` temporary and copying the content of this temporary queue to the current one `st_crt_lvl` at the end processing of each level of the binary tree.

This could be achieved by keeping just a single queue (without any temporary storage) and level order traversal by standard `bfs` algorithm, but since we want zig-zag order traversal at each level, it's more elegant to have a temporary queue, so that the temporary queue only keeps the next level elements and when processing of the current level elements is done, the current queue points to the next level.

With some modification of your code, along with an example tree:

```
def zigzagLevelOrder(A):

    st_crt_lvl = [A] # initialize
    ans_list = []   

    level = 0
    while st_crt_lvl: # check if all levels are processed
        st_nxt_lvl =[] # temporary queue to hold the next level elements
        tmp = [] # temporary storage to append to the ans_list 
        while st_crt_lvl:
            u = st_crt_lvl.pop(0)
            tmp.append(u.val) 
            if u.left:
                st_nxt_lvl.append(u.left)
            if u.right:
                st_nxt_lvl.append(u.right)                
        if (len(tmp) > 0): # if tmp is not empty
            if level % 2 == 1: # ensure zig-zag level order traversal
                tmp = tmp[::-1]
            ans_list.append(tmp)
        st_crt_lvl = st_nxt_lvl  # copy the temporary queue to the current queue      
        level += 1

    return ans_list


class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, left, right, data):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.val = data

A = BinaryTree(None, None, 3)
A.left = BinaryTree(None, None, 9)
A.right = BinaryTree(None, None, 20)
A.left.left = BinaryTree(None, None, 1)
A.left.right = BinaryTree(None, None, 2)
A.right.left = BinaryTree(None, None, 15)
A.right.right = BinaryTree(None, None, 7)
zigzagLevelOrder(A)
# [[3], [20, 9], [1, 2, 15, 7]]
```

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if you explain what you did here. It seems obvious to you that you eliminated copying the elements from the "next" stack to the "current" stack by just making an assignment, but the OP might not fully understand how that works or why it's faster.

Comment: Sure I shall add explanations

Answer (score -1):

You can use a breadth-first search:

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['left', 'right', 'value']}
  def __contains__(self, _val):
   if self.value != _val and self.left is None and self.right is None:
     return False
   return True if self.value == _val else any([_val in [[], self.left][self.left is not None], _val in [[], self.right][self.right is not None]])
  def __lookup(self, _val, _depth = 0):
    if self.value == _val:
      return _depth
    return getattr(self, 'left' if _val in self.left else 'right').__lookup(_val, _depth+1)
  def __getitem__(self, _val):
    return self.__lookup(_val)    

def bfs(_head):
  _d = deque([_head])
  _seen = []
  _last = None
  _final_result = defaultdict(list)
  while _d:
   _current = _d.popleft()
   if _current.value not in _seen:
      _seen.append(_current.value)
      _r = list(filter(None, [getattr(_current, i, None) for i in ['left', 'right']]))
      _d.extend(_r)
      _final_result[_head[_current.value]].append(_current.value)
  marker = iter(range(len(_final_result)))
  return [i[::-1] if next(marker)%2 else i for _, i in sorted(_final_result.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

---

When constructing the same tree in the example from the link in the question, the output is:

```
t = Tree(value=3, left=Tree(value=9), right=Tree(value=20, left=Tree(value=15), right=Tree(value=7)))
print(bfs(t))
```

Output:

```
[[3], [20, 9], [15, 7]]
```

This solution uses the [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to traverse the tree horizontally. However, since a (complete) binary tree has two children, only two values will be added to the queue. Therefore, in order to determine the current tree level the search has reached, a method to find the depth of a particular value has to be implemented in the tree (`__getitem__` and `__lookup`).